# Convert Json Data into a noraml string in metro application?

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, microsoft-metro

I hav a metro application in which i'm calling a service which displays the output in json format.
The output data of my service is as shown:

```
   {"AssignedTo":"8",
   "AssignedUserName":"james",
   "ExpectedCompletionDate":"\/Date(1343673000000)\/",
   "Priority":"Yes",
   "Status":"Open",
   "Description":"rtrtrtrtrtr",
   "EntityID":"Q0000621",
   "EntityType":"Deal",
   "Parameters":{"Account":"fds","TaskType":"Work log"},
   "SysGenerated":false,
   "UserID":"1"}
```

I want to convert that json data into a normal string format so that i can display the data in my listview.

Comment: Please give example of what you mean by normal string

Comment: Means i want to print above values one-by-one in my listview.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
public class DataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public string AssignedTo
{
get;set;
}
```

...
    public bool SysGenerated
    {
    get;set;
    }
    public string UserID
    {
    get;set;
    }

```
public DataSource(string jsonContent)
{
// use reflection to create the class
}
}
```

or

```
string data = string.Concact(jsonContent);
```

?